# normal compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

‎I ‎have ‎recently  started normal operations, but I  face with problems in this ‎regard.‎‎ please guide ‎me.‎

**a: ‎let‎ ‎$  T ‎\in K ( H ) $‎ ‎be‎    ‎normal, ‎show that ‎‎‎$‎T ‎\geq 0 ‎‎‎‎‎$ ‎if ‎only ‎if ‎all eigenvalues  of the operator is equal to zero..‎‎**

**b:‎‎‎let‎ ‎$  T ‎\in K ( H ) $‎ ‎be‎ ‎$ T ‎\geq ‎0‎ $‎, ‎show ‎that‎ There ‎is a‎ ‎‎ positive and unique compact actuator ‎$  ‎A‎$‎ so ‎that‎ ‎$ ‎A‎^{2} =‎ ‎T‎. $‎**

Comment: Have you seen the continuous functional calculus?

Comment: yes, I study about Functional calculus theorem for continuous functions, but i can not solve The above statement .

Comment: (a) looks wrong.

Comment: (a) is wrong. Any operator on a finite-dimensional space is compact, and many are positive (hence normal) and have nonzero spectrum.

Comment: What is the definition of a positive operator you are using? There are several equivalent starting places.

Comment: I suspect (a) should read "greater than or equal to zero".